# How to take a snapshot from a widget tree without using RepaintBoundary?

Tags: flutter

I want to take a snapshot from a widget tree, so I wrap the tree in a RepaintBoundary widget and use its key to do the work.It works, but on older devices (ex: i6) it crashes.
I think the reason is it rebuilds too often and the RepaintBoundary caching images cause OOM, but I can't fix the rebuilds question for some reason.
So I want to know how to write the 'toImage' method on myown?
Here's what I've done, but it comes out nothing.

```
class ToImageBoxRender extends RenderProxyBox {
  ToImageBoxRender({RenderBox child}) : super(child);

  Future<ui.Image> toImage({double pixelRatio = 1.0}) {
    assert(!debugNeedsPaint);
    final OffsetLayer offsetLayer = layer as OffsetLayer;
    return offsetLayer.toImage(Offset.zero & size, pixelRatio: pixelRatio);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset offset) {
    if (child != null) {
      context.paintChild(child, offset);
      layer = OffsetLayer();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: add `@override
  bool get isRepaintBoundary => true;`

Comment: thanks for your response, I tried`@override   bool get isRepaintBoundary => true;` and it will crash. I think the reason is if you add that override, the framework will think this RenderBox is a RepaintBoundary.

Comment: see `class Screenshot extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
Screenshot({Key key, Widget child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

@override RenderObject createRenderObject(BuildContext context) => RenderScreenshot();
}

class RenderScreenshot extends RenderProxyBox {
@override bool get isRepaintBoundary => true;

Future<ui.Image> screenshot() {
OffsetLayer _layer = layer;
return _layer.toImage(_layer.offset & size);
}
}`

Comment: thanks pskink, but I think the result will be the same because `@override bool get isRepaintBoundary => true;`, I think I have to find another solution to reach the effect I want.

Comment: so did you call `screenshot()` method? if so, what is the exact result?  does it crash? does it hang? anything else?

Comment: It crashes when the target layout is building before I call the method. I test this program on deviceA(4GB) deviceB(1GB) deviceC(2GB), and it works ok on deviceA, but crash on deviceB&C

Comment: what is the `size` of `Screenshot`? tried to use it not on the whole screen but rather on some 100x100 `Container` for example?

Comment: it works on a smaller widget, but the target I want to take `screenShot` is a list of `widget` which contains 3~5 images. What I'm trying to do is make a list of small picture of those `widgets` and shows them on the right side of the screen.

Comment: I guess the memory problem is really hard to solve, so now I'm going to try another way, I really appreciate for your response pskink, have a nice day.

Comment: oh, I haven't tried that. I'll give it a chance. Thanks.